# Android, how to stop reading getView() function again, if the content is already downloaded in the ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am a newbie Android guy.

I have a ListView displaying images on every element of the ListView, It works fine... but when I start to scrolling I have realized my image is downloaded again if it is displayed in the screen of my phone device!

How could I stop reloading the images or all the content of the in ListView again?
Or how could I avoid reading the getView() function again If I have already downloaded all its content?

Comment: If you are downloading stuff from the internet then you should cache it so that you don't need to download it over and over.

Comment: To expand on CaseyB's suggestion, I'd recommend you watch the [Turbo-charge your UI talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA) Watch the first section to see if you implementing the adapter properly. Also start watching from 50:00 for a simple example of a bitmap cache. In fact watch the whole video.

Comment: have you try to use Picasso  see the following link   https://square.github.io/picasso

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create an efficient adapter with different view types. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660417/android-efficientadapter-with-two-different-views).

It's fairly simple. Just need to override getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount. Then you can count on convertView being the correct view type.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you need to implement a caching mechanism in your code. If the image is already downloaded, save it to a temp file and show it directly from the file without redownloading.

To achieve this easier, you may use an Android image library such as:

- https://github.com/bumptech/glide - Glide is a fast and efficient open source media management and image loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and disk caching, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use interface.
- https://square.github.io/picasso - Images add much-needed context and visual flair to Android applications. Picasso allows for hassle-free image loading in your application—often in one line of code!
  Many common pitfalls of image loading on Android are handled automatically by Picasso:

Handling ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
Automatic memory and disk caching.

- https://github.com/facebook/fresco - Fresco is a powerful system for displaying images in Android applications.

Fresco takes care of image loading and display, so you don't have to. It will load images from the network, local storage, or local resources, and display a placeholder until the image has arrived. It has two levels of cache; one in memory and another in internal storage.

- https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader - Powerful and flexible library for loading, caching and displaying images on Android.
- https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view - Powerful and flexible library for loading, caching and displaying images on Android.

Here are some more libs https://gist.github.com/bgizdov/22ab86073bc3b8a7c33ae93d87952aaa