# how to stop executing the getView() method while scrolling the ListView items using SimpleAdapter in android

Tags: android

i have used SimpleAdapter to display a list of items in a listview.While displaying the getView() is called every time to display every list item with different layout.Here i got succeeded in doing so.But here the problem is whenever i scroll the list items again the getView() method is executing and iam getting the unreliable results.Here my requirement is i dont want to execute the getView() method while scrolling the listview.Any body please guide me out of this situation.

Comment: getview method is called everytime a list is scrolled as the items are created/recreated on scrolling. u can post ur code. May be then somethng could be thought of

Comment: Please post your listactivity code.  The way I created a listview, extending listActivity, and using the SimpleCusorAdapter within the fillData method, I didn't have to deal with doing anything with getView.

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behaviour of the ListView, it is automatically buffered. So as you scroll, new items are inflated and added and the old ones are knocked off. This mechanism works by calling your overridden getView() method.

If you don't want this then just use a LinearLayout inside a scrollview and manually populate it with your list items. You can even still use your adapter by using:

```
linear.addView(adapter.getView(index, null, linear));
```

Hope this helps!

I want to add one thing that if 
you have more than one records in your adapter just use a for loop like this.

```
ArrayAdapter<Question> adapter = MyCustomArrayAdapter
                .GetArrayAdapterInstance(this, flag1, flag1, lst_question);

    for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++)
    {
        linear.addView(adapter.getView(i, null, linear));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same problem, and here is our response ! 
[Android, how to stop reading getView() function again, if the content is already downloaded in the ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009121/android-how-to-stop-reading-getview-function-again-if-the-content-is-already)

Let me know if it work for you ;)