# Saving user input while adding/removing ListView items in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView which multiple contains checkboxes for user input. I have two buttons add and remove to add and remove list items respectively.
I am using BaseAdapter for ListView and notifying the ListView using notifyDataSetChanged()

Anytime I add/remove the items. The user input in the list gets cleared. I think it's because the list is getting rebuilt everytime. Any ideas on how to keep the user input while add/remove the items in listView ?

Comment: you need to use View holder ...in your adapter

Answer (score 0):

in listview you have only one option is to use notifyDatasetChanged() with adapter. just dont clear your whole list just do add/remove and then notify adapter or use Recycclerview instead.

With recyclerview you have many options like notifyDataInserted, notifyDataRemoved, range inserted, range removed etc.

You can find a good example [here](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html)

Answer (score 0):

i think your programme is reading getView() function again. see the below code to avoid it, it is copy pasted but it may give you some idea-

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null) {
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, null);
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);

return convertView;
}
```

you can refer this link for more info-0
[Android, how to stop reading getView() function again, if the content is already downloaded in the ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009121/android-how-to-stop-reading-getview-function-again-if-the-content-is-already)