# Android Listview Position is 0 on item selection

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a custom adapter for my list view (extends ArrayAdapter). The list loads fine. However, when I click on an item in my list, i.e. the 5th item in the list, the position in getView is always 0 instead of 5. It crashes because `convertView` is no longer `null` If it is 0, the `header`variable should be initialized to the `R.id.listHeaderTv` TextView, but it can't find it and ends up being null. 
How do I fix the `position` problem and `convertView` not being null anymore?

EDIT: **After checking onItemClick method, the position is correct. The only problem then is that after the onItemClick method, getView is being called and crashes there because the view is not being inflated.**

LOGCAT:

```
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at moflow.adapters.CatalogListAdapter.getView(CatalogListAdapter.java:66)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1272)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1558)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-27 16:35:25.280: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Adapter:

```
@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return catalog.size();
        }

    @Override
            public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
                View v = convertView;
                CatalogItem item = getItem( position );

                if ( v == null ) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = ( LayoutInflater ) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

                    if ( item.header )
                        v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.sec_header, null );
                    else
                        v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.sec_item, null );
                }

                if ( item.header ) {
                    TextView header = ( TextView ) v.findViewById( R.id.listHeaderTV );
                    header.setText( item.name );
                    header.setEnabled( false );
                } else {
                    TextView sectionItem = ( TextView ) v.findViewById( R.id.listCreatureNameTV );
                    sectionItem.setText( item.name );
                }

                return v;
            }
```

Comment: Is there any need at all to have the v == null check? Also, I guess position does not matter in the case of an item click. It gets the right position in the onItemClick method, but then I wonder why getView is even being called on an onItemClick.

Comment: You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660417/android-efficientadapter-with-two-different-views) SO question, right now, as you have noticed, it doesn't work well when convertView isn't null, since it now has layout information that you may or may not have when setting.

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers what is your problem, is your position of selected list item returns 0 for the 5th item ..?

Comment: What is line 66 in CatalogListAdapter?

Comment: Where is your code for clicking on the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, don't know where Sam's answer went but he was correct about overriding those two methods getItemViewType() and getViewTypeCount(). I also got help from this page: http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-listview-with-section-header.html

Here's the code that ended up working for me:

```
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType( position );

        if ( convertView == null ) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch( type ) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.sec_item, null );
                    holder.tv = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.listCreatureNameTV );
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.sec_header, null );
                    holder.tv = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.listHeaderTV );
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag( holder );
        } else {
            holder = ( ViewHolder ) convertView.getTag();
        }

        CatalogItem item = getItem( position );
        holder.tv.setText( item.name );

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tv;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`getView()` is supposed to produce the view to be displayed. To get the click events, you'll want set on OnItemClickListener such as this:

```
new OnItemClickListener() {
    // @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
         Toast.makeText(ListRecords.this,"Clicked item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     });
```

... and ignore `convertView` for the time being.